# access logger from other js modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am just starting in nodejs.

I am instantiating a logger (Pino) in server.js which is the entry point. I only want to create one instance of that logger and use it in other modules.

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const pino = require('pino');
const log = pino({ level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info' });

const ping = require('./routes/ping'); //new

const app = express();
app.use('/api/ping', ping);

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`API server started on ${port}... ^C to end`);
});

module.exports = { app, log }; //edited
```

So in ping.js how do I get access to log in services.js?

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { log }  = require('../server'); //edited

router.get('/', async function(req, res) {
  log.info('someone pinged');
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Edited with suggestions.

Comment: `export {log}` in server.js and require it in whatever file. It will be the same instance. I like to have a config file where I instantiate such things and import everywhere. Same result but that's just preference.

Comment: ahh, I thought if you had it in a config files, for example, each "require" would create a new instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the logger as a property on your `app` object or on `app.locals`. Then a reference to it will be accessible through `req.app.logger` or `req.app.locals.logger` or whatever in your middlewares and route handlers.

Comment: worked. "app.log = log;"  req.app.log.info("asdf");

Comment: how do I access it in other modules that don't have req?
const { log } = require('../server.js'); is undefined

Comment: What are these other modules doing in your Express app if they don't have access to `app` or `req`? If they're just utility or helper functions, you can use a similar dependency-injection pattern and just pass the logger reference as an argument when you invoke them.

Comment: If you're more comfortable with object-oriented stuff and want to go that route and create a singleton, maybe this article would be helpful: https://medium.com/@maheshkumawat_83392/node-js-design-patterns-singleton-pattern-series-1-1e0ab71e3edf

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const ping = require('./routes/ping');

const pino = require('pino');
const log = pino({ level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info' });

var app = module.exports = express();

app
  .use('/api/ping', ping);

const port = config.SERVER_PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`API server started on ${port}... ^C to end`);
});

module.exports = {app,pino}
```

Now you can import the same pino instance anywhere.

```
const log = require('./server.js').pino
```

Comment: It comes across as undefined.

Comment: It shouldn't, just check to make sure your path is correct . The example assumes that your other file is in the same directory as `server.js`

Comment: yes, I used  "const log  = require('../server').pino;" since ping.js is in ./routes

Comment: Its probably the order then .. Try moving ping below the instantiation of pino

Comment: let me create a little test app.

Comment: no need, its the order.. when you do `const ping = require('./routes/ping');` It runs `ping.js` which requires `pino` which has not been instantiated in server.js yet. Anyways good luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194615/discussion-between-gina-marano-and-johnsnow).

Comment: I'm sorry I can't explain this further than I already have, its not possible